# What is POSIX-compatible mode in Linux?

Tags: command-line, bash, emulation

The book says :

> When in POSIX-compatible mode, **bash**
>   will emulate **sh**.

What does this mean? What is meant by emulation in simple layman terms?

Comment: "To emulate" in simple layman terms means "to act like". `bash` has a number of extensions to the `sh` specification and probably (not sure) even cases, where it behaves differently from `sh`. But when in emulation mode, it tries to be as compatible as possible to the specification of `sh`. Find a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/4271479

Comment: Which book? Do you want [a definition of "emulate"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emulate), or an explanation of POSIX compatibility?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a Linux thing, it's a bash thing. Bash is just one of many shells. Bash is the "Bourne again shell" and was released as a replacement of the original Bourne Shell, `sh`.

POSIX is a set of standards defining how POSIX-compliant systems should work. The POSIX shell standard can be found [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html). Bash has many features not present in `sh` and is not actually a POSIX compliant shell.

This is why the `--posix` option is provided. As explained in `man bash` (emphasis mine):

> If bash is invoked with the name sh, it  tries  to  mimic  the 
>   startup    behavior  of  historical  versions  of sh as closely as
>   possible, while    conforming to the POSIX standard as well.  When
>   invoked as an  interactive  login  shell, or a non-interactive
>   shell with the --login option, it first attempts to read and
>   execute commands from /etc/profile and ~/.profile, in that 
>   order. The --noprofile  option may be used to inhibit this
>   behavior.  **When invoked as an interactive shell with the name
>   sh, bash  looks for the variable ENV, expands its value if it is 
>   defined, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read 
>   and execute. Since a shell invoked as sh does not attempt to read
>   and execute commands from any other startup files, the --rcfile
>   option has  no effect**.   A  non-interactive  shell  invoked  with
>   the name sh does not    attempt to read any other startup files. 
>   When  invoked  as  sh,  bash    enters posix mode after the startup
>   files are read.
>
> When  bash  is  started in posix mode, as with the --posix command
>   line    option, it follows the POSIX standard for startup files.  In
>   this mode, interactive  shells  expand  the ENV variable and
>   commands are read and executed from the file whose name is  the
>   expanded  value. No other startup files are read.

This means that if you run `sh`, or `bash --posix`, to start an interactive shell, your `~/.bahsrc` file is ignored and, instead, the file saved as `$ENV` (if any) is read. To illustrate, I have added `echo "read .bashrc"` to my `~/.bashrc`:

```
$ bash
read .bashrc  ## message was printed, ~/.bashrc was read
$ sh
sh-4.3$       ## no message printed, ~/.bashrc was not read
```

If I now set `$ENV`:

```
$ export ENV="~/.bashrc"
$ sh
read .bashrc
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Ubuntu has chosen to make `/bin/sh` a synlink to `/bin/dash`. Dash is yet another shell and is actually a POSIX-compliant one. This means that in order to observe the behavior I described above, you need to use a different `sh`<sup>1</sup>. On Ubuntu, you need to create a file called `sh` that is a symlink to `/bin/bash`:

```
$ ln -s /bin/bash ~/sh
```

You now have a file called `sh` in your home directory. Use that to demonstrate the differences I explained above:

```
$ ls -l ~/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 9 May  2 14:03 /home/terdon/sh -> /bin/bash
$ ~/sh
read .bashrc
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Actually, the behavior will look as though it's the same, `~/.bashrc` will be ignored, but that's just because `dash` is not `bash` and has no business reading the bash-specific `~/.bashrc` anyway. However, `dash` also ignores `$ENV` so you need to use the link to `/bin/bash` to see that.</sub>

Comment: First time I hear about `dash`. Is it still around today (2020)?

Comment: @wlad yes, of course. Everything in this answer should still be relevant. It's only been 3 and a half years, after all.

Comment: There are arguably corners where `dash` deviates from POSIX, though the intent is certainly to eventually make it 100% compliant.